# Why does an rspec feature spec with javascript not do test teardown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have several non-javascript specs that use the ui to create and edit records.
When I run these specs the test database records are automatically removed for me by the rspec teardown for each test.

However the test below which is the first one to have `:js => true` for some ajax stuff isn't doing tear down of the records afterwards and then tests start to break because the database is no longer empty correctly when they start.  The link and the group rows still exist in the test database.

```
# spec/features/verifying_link_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

describe "verification", :js => true, :type => :feature do

  before :all do
    User.create(:username => 'r@google.com', :password => 'esceptio')
  end 

  before :each do
    visit '/ladmin/login'
    fill_in 'username', :with => 'r@google.com'
    fill_in 'password', :with => 'esceptio'
    find('input[value="Login"]').click
  end 

  it "lets me verify a link" do
    find('div#side div a', text: 'New Group').click
    fill_in 'group[group_name]', with: 'Group Add'
    click_button 'Save'
    find('div#side div a', text: 'New Link').click
    fill_in 'link[url_address]', with: 'http://www.a.com/newtest9876link'
    fill_in 'link[alt_text]', with: 'abcd9876'
    click_button 'Save'
    this_year=Time.now.strftime('%Y')
    l=Link.first
    l.update_attribute(:verified_date, nil)
    expect(Link.count).to eq 1
    visit links_path
    find('a', text: "verify")
    click_link("verify", match: :first)
    sleep(3)
    expect(page).to have_content(this_year)
  end 

end
```

Right now I am using a workaround solution of using the ui to delete the records (below) but this should not be necessary

```
    # added at bottom of spec
    click_link('Details')
    click_link('Delete')
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
    click_link('Groups')
    click_link('Delete')
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

None of my other unit tests or feature tests (except this one with js) have this problem.  They all create records that get removed automatically.

Comment: Are you using the database_cleaner gem?  What are you using to run the JS tests, selenium, phantomjs, chromedriver?

Comment: I am not using the database cleaner gem.  I am considering it.  As much of what I am doing is for learning though I'd like to know why this test has this issue (and others don't).  I also have some concerns about a strategy to truncate the database between each test and whether there would be any performance implications.  I am using RSpec & Capybara which I believe is using selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem to clean your database out between tests.  Rspec wraps everything in a transaction and rolling it back once the example is finished.  However, when you start using javascript you might be saving the data outside of the rspec transaction and then the database never reverts to its original state.

Truncation is slower than the transaction strategy.  However you may only need the truncation strategy with JS tests.  You could follow this guide to setup the database cleaner gem in that manner: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

If you find your tests taking eons, you might want to investigate some time looking at a gem that preloads your environment.  I highly recommend [zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus)